# Animation in powerpoint of mathematical proofs

Tags: animation, microsoft-powerpoint, mathematics

I'm working on a powerpoint presentation of a mathematical proof. I'm showing it using a tabel of 2 columns - one is with the mathematical statements and the other is with the rationale. Meaning each row has a statement and it's rationale.

I want to show the proof using animation as follow:
A click reveales a cell, then its adjacent cell in the same row abd the next click will reveal the cell in the next row etc'. Now I can use the animation pane to control this but this would be a reall hassle with a lot of rows.

Does someone know an efficient way to do this?

Comment: PPt presentation of a proof? What the f**k? Students may well read it as a whole, no need to at first hide the prewritten explanations. Teacher's job is to construct the proof in real time in front of the students and justify it by explaining what reasoning has been made for each step. Having a certain suggestive ability which forces the students to think along right paths is the whole thing. Preachers, some theater actors and wannabe dictators have the same ability. As far as I can imagine the construction is often non-linear. A piece of chalk is much more flexible than PPt. (continues)

Comment: (continued) If you skip the actual teaching and want to unhide boxes of formulas and texts, prepare the whole story as a background image and move aside or delete opaque rectangles which are drawn to hide the prepared formulas and explanations.